# How to keep rest of string using word2number library in Python

Tags: python

I have a string in Python like this:

```
a = "one house"
```

For my program I need to convert that one into a literal 1, which I use the **word2number** library for in Python.

Except, when I convert it, I get this.

```
a = "one house"
a = w2n.word_to_num(a)
print(a)
>> 1
```

I want to retain the "house" and make the string like this:

```
>> "1 house"
```

Answer (score 2):

With no prior information about the position of the number:

```
a = 'One house in the middle of three woods'
s = a.split()
o = []
for word in s:
    try:
        o += [str(w2n.word_to_number(word))]
    except ValueError:
        o += [word] 


print(' '.join(o))

output:: '1 house in the middle of 3 woods'
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the word2number module returns an integer, this means that the house part cannot be retained as it is a string. If you know that the number is always going to be the first word, you could try:

```
a = "one house"
a_list = a.split(' ')
a_list[0] = str(w2n.word_to_num(a_list[0]))
print(' '.join(a_list))
```

Whereby you split the string into multiple strings in a list, run the `word_to_num` function on the first string and then recreate the string using `.join()`